# Running DataJpaTest with PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wrote a jpa test with Spring Boot as explained here:
https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTests {

@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;

...
}
```

This configures a in-memory db by default. How can I configure this test, that it uses my local PostgreSQL db?

Comment: Have you tried to use your application.properties to define a DB?

Comment: Yes, I configured the PostgrSQL in the application.properties and added the corresponding Postgres dependency.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to use the same datasource as your regular application you can use:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
```

Answer (score 13):

`@DataJpaTest` contains `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
```

It's enough. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it too in `application.yml` or `application.properties`

```
spring:
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Spring 2.6.4) I had to specify datasource in test/resources/application.yaml additionally to main/resources/application.yaml